# IntelliJ not recognising python import

Tags: python, intellij-idea, import, module

Hi in IntelliJ I can run python programs fine, but the imports such as "import pandas as pd" are not recognised by IntelliJ in that it displays a red squiggly line underneath.

Does anyone know how to resolve these symbols? I have tried looking at project structure but cannot change anything that resolves the issue. It is pretty frustrating to have these red lines everywhere.

Comment: try using pycharm instead of intelliJ as it is directly made for python

Comment: Thanks, we may do this but we wanted to use one IDE across Scala, Java and Python so would prefer to use IntelliJ for all development

Comment: Decided to use pycharm in the end, at least both IntelliJ and Pycharm are very similar